# GitLab CI/CD merge request diff list (with powershell executor)

Tags: powershell, gitlab, cicd

I am not able to pull data with a list of changed files (based ona merge request) from GitLab API /merge_requests/iid/diff (endpoint does not exist for our instance) so I tried to extract it with a job script.

I have a gitlab runner installed on a remote machine with powershell executor and registered with GitLab.

.yaml:

```
 info-job:  
  stage: build  
  tags: testrunner  
  script: git diff --name-only remotes/origin/$(CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME)...(remotes/origin/$(CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME)
```

Execution of this job results in the following error:

```
  fatal: ambiguous argument 'remotes/origin/...remotes/origin/main': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

How to pull it off with a script?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `..` and not `...`?

Comment: This isn't powershell syntax, unless something else handles it:  `$(CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME)`

Comment: .. instead of ... is indeed correct, however I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: How should the script look like with a proper syntax?

Comment: Looks like the `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME` variable isn't populating for some reason. Same thing with `${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}`?

Comment: Also, you can't use unescaped `(` characters (except as part of `$(...)`) in an unquoted argument; best to use `"..."` around the entire argument.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I'm trying to do the same with Python script and passing var from CI "--main $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME --branch $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" - both vars are correct. And I call from pythin "repo.git.diff("remotes/origin/{}".format(source), "remotes/origin/{}".format(main))"